# Extracting all the values from ONLY a column as list based on an if condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
Host    DB    Status
001     A     ONLINE
001     B     ONLINE
001     C     OFFLINE
001     D     OFFLINE
```

I want list of all DB's which have status as offline. I cant do loop as I am getting this data in a loop for each server and at the same time after getting I need to clean it.

In output I want`[C,D]`

I tried this:

```
temp_df.loc[temp_df.STATE=="OFFLINE","Status"]["DB"]
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(df[df['Status']=='OFFLINE']['DB'].tolist())
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: This is giving me null data as well

Comment: You mean if DB is NaN or blank?

Comment: no I mean if there is no Offline it is giving empty list

Comment: If there is no OFFLINE, it is going to be an empty list. What do you want populated if there is no OFFLINE?

Comment: I wanted it doesnt even show that values except those who are online. I added additional step to check if list if empty or not. Added a bit more complexity to the code because of this.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code

```
temp_df.loc[temp_df.Status=="OFFLINE","DB"].to_numpy()
```